# how to set a boolean property in unity3d CGprogram shader?

Tags: opengl, unity-game-engine, shader, cg

I am writing a shader for unity3d and I want to specify the properties of the shader in i.e like -

```
Shader "GraphicsQuality/MediumScan" {
Properties {
    _Color ("Main Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
    _SpecColor ("Specular Color", Color) = (0.5,0.5,0.5,1)
    _Shininess ("Shininess", Range (0.01, 1)) = 0.078125
    _MainTex ("Base (RGB) RefStrGloss (A)", 2D) = "white" {}
    _BumpMap ("Normalmap", 2D) = "bump" {}
    _RimColor ("Rim Color", Color) = (0.48,0.78,1.0,0.0)
    _RimPower ("Rim Power", Range(0,8.0)) = 3.0
}
```

But these properties are for color, range, float etc but I want to input a boolean value how can i do it i tried something like-

```
Properties{
    _MainTex ("Particle Texture", 2D) = "white" {
    _isBending("is Bending",bool) = true
}
SubShader{
        Pass{
            CGPROGRAM

                #pragma vertex vert
                #pragma fragment frag

                sampler2D _MainTex;
                bool _isBending;
.......continuing
```

but this doesnt work I am not able to get the boolean property "_isBending" and I get a Error instead in the line

```
  _isBending("is Bending",bool) = true
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
[MaterialToggle] _isBending("is Bending", Float) = 0
```

or

```
[Toggle] _isBending("is Bending", Float) = 0
```

At least you will have a visual toggle button.

Answer (score 2):

Booleans are not supported in Unity shader properties. To work around this try and use a float instead.
See this page for more info: 
http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Components/SL-Properties.html